# Any attributes to ensure an HTML form can't be submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, server-rendering

I want to server-render an HTML form in such a way that it is **not submittable** *until* it has been asynchronously enhanced by my JavaScript.

It looks like there's no `disabled` attribute for the `form` element [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

I could add a `disabled` attribute to the submit button (and then later remove this with JavaScript when ready), but the user could still submit the form by focusing any input and pressing `Enter`.

Is there any way to prevent submission without JavaScript (short of just hiding the form entirely in the server-rendered HTML, and unhiding it with JS)?

Comment: Without JS? No. The best you could do is leave the form action empty and apply it only when ready.

Comment: @Utkanos An empty `action` results in the form being submitted to the same URL…

Comment: prevent the default submission event on the `form` element and make your `AJAX` logic in there.

Comment: You could use a required attribute on a field hidden off the page and then remove that field when your js has run

Comment: @deceze; correct - `javascript:void(0)` or `#` would do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do

```
onsubmit="return false"
```

on the `form` tag:

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <label>input
    <input type="text" name="input" name="a" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This won't prevent users who've disabled JavaScript from submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

use `type="button"` attribute to your submit button and then change it to `type="submit"`

Comment: this wouldn't prevent the pressing return in a field

Comment: even on pressing ENTER in text fields this will prevent form to get Submit until you are submitting form via script

Comment: No it doesn't, type something in the textbox and press  enter - the form submits: http://jsfiddle.net/b0prc8uy/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, answering my own question - it turns out it's easy to make a form unsubmittable (in Chrome 69 at least) just by disabling the submit button.

When the only submit button is disabled, then even focusing a text field and pressing `Enter` does not submit the form.